# finding new image width and height in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

The width of the image uploaded by the user is ‘W' and height is ‘H'
Keeping in mind the following four constraints:
1. The resized image should have the same aspect ratio( width/height) as the aspect ratio of the image uploaded by the user.
2. The width of the resized image should be as close as possible to 200 px & never more than 200px.
3. The height of the resized image should be as close as possible to 300 px & never more than 300 px.
4. The quality of the resized image should not be inferior to the image uploaded by the user. That means image should never be stretched.

You have to compute the w_new and h_new to which this image of WxH should be resized to while meeting ALL the above mentioned 4 constraints.

Comment: Is it a scholar exercise?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score -1):

ratio = w / h

h = 200 / ratio.

if h is <= 300 then you found your answer.

else: w = 300 * ratio